# Propose delegatecall via the safe-apps-sdk

Tags: gnosis-safe, delegatecall, safe-apps-sdk

Is the [safe-apps-sdk](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/master/packages/safe-apps-sdk) only meant to be used when we don't need to propose a delegatecall to the safe?

It seems that the safe-apps-sdk uses [MultiSendCallOnly.sol](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/MultiSendCallOnly.sol).
Is it possible to customize the mutisend contract used by safe-apps-sdk to use the [MultiSend.sol](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/MultiSend.sol) contract instead?

If so, is there a way to specify the operation parameter of transactions (so that it can be set to delegatecall)?

If not, what is the best way to propose a bundle of transactions to the Safe, that consists of both call and delegatecall transactions (from within a Safe app)?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible via `safe-apps-sdk` or Safe apps in general due to security concerns. The `DELEGATECALL` is meant to be used only by advanced users, so the only way to create such a transaction is via a script.